# Keyword If Statements

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

What keyword precedes the suite that will be executed if the condition in an if statement is false?

This questions is for a homework I am having difficulty with in Python. I have tried to look int he chapters to get the information.

Comment: Where *else* have you looked before posting here?  This is high on the  lookupable scale...

Comment: Yea, where ***else*** have you looked?

Comment: I am very new to programming and having difficulty with the terminology. I am honestly having trouble figuriong out how to look something like this up. If this question has been answered already I will be more then happy to look it up somwhere.

Answer (score 6):

The wording of your question is difficult to understand, but I think this hint is what you are trying to figure out:

```
if <some condition goes here>:
    <statements to execute if the statement is true>
<something goes here>:
    <statements to execute if the statement is false>
```

What word goes in place of `<something goes here>`?

Comment: nice and without just giving away the answer ... I couldnt figure out what the question was asking

Comment: Nitpick: missing colon on `<something goes here>`, if `<something goes here>` is supposed to be the keyword.

Comment: The requirements go in the place of something goes here. Correct?

Comment: Note that there are multiple things that can go in place of `<somthing goes here>`.

Comment: The requirements are written out first. Then the statement as it would be true.

Comment: @user2640086 The colon is part of the <something goes here> =p (At least that's the story I'm sticking with...)

Comment: @arshajii True. Since my answer is a hint to the OPs question, I think there is only one right answer in that context.

Comment: @user2640086 The question is looking for a specific **keyword** (i.e. a single word) that goes in place of `<something goes here>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can find Python's full grammar specification [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html). Here's the structure of an `if`-statement:

```
if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
```